# SQL 2008 - Trying to compare NVARCHAR (128) to datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime

I have to compare two tables and the common link has to be the date field.  My issue is that on one the date is NVARCHAR(128) YYYYMMDDHHMM and the other is datetime YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.MMM.   I only need YYYYMMDDHHMM to match.

Code:

```
SELECT        ps_Patients.Identifier, ps_Patients.Source_Group, msg_ReportingEvent.EncounterDate, msg_ReportingEvent.EventDateTime
FROM            msg_ReportingEvent INNER JOIN
                         ps_Patients ON msg_ReportingEvent.PatientId = ps_Patients.PatientId AND msg_ReportingEvent.EncounterDate = ps_Patients.Created
```

Comment: You are really making things hard for yourself, can you not add a DateTime column to “the one” table and join against that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say your `ps_Patients.Created` is in Datetime datatype and you want to convert it to `YYYYMMDDHHMM`format to join to other table, you would do something like this... very inefficient but this seems to be the only way.

```
SELECT  ps_Patients.Identifier
      , ps_Patients.Source_Group
      , msg_ReportingEvent.EncounterDate
      , msg_ReportingEvent.EventDateTime
FROM  msg_ReportingEvent INNER JOIN ps_Patients 
ON msg_ReportingEvent.PatientId = ps_Patients.PatientId 
AND msg_ReportingEvent.EncounterDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), ps_Patients.Created, 112)
                                       + RIGHT('00' + CAST(DATEPART(HOUR,ps_Patients.Created) AS NVARCHAR(2)),2)
                                       +RIGHT('00' + CAST(DATEPART(MINUTE,ps_Patients.Created) AS NVARCHAR(2)),2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it two different ways

```
CAST(nvarcharField AS DATETIME)
```

or the other way to do it would be

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR,nvarcharField,121)
```